# Laravel Get Requste with multiple tokens

Tags: php, laravel, get, laravel-10

I'm working on a simple project in Laravel 10

In the database, I have a table **tokens** and in the column, there is a set of special tokens

I want to fetch them all and call them in URL get, I do that but it doesn't repeat the connection with the remaining **tokens** it just fetches them in JSON form

in **TokensController.php**

I have more than one tokens

I fetch tokens from the database:

```
$codes = UsersTokens::select('tokens')->get();
```

Tokens = "6374784926";

Tokens = "8274748264";

Tokens = "8489155538";

Tokens = "15536485926";

I call like this

```
foreach ($codes as $code){
$activeOrders = Http::asJson()->withToken($code->tokens)->get('https://api.example.com/v2/api');
return $activeOrders;
}
```

But it doesn't work, tokens form DB **UsersTokens** as it looks JSON!

I want to fetch the link with multiple tokens, and it fetches all the contact information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first question there is mistake with parameter in call ($codes should be $code):
Case 1 (using all tokens as url params):

```
$num = count($codes);
$tokens_request = '';   
foreach ($codes as $key => $code){
    $tokens_request .= 'tokens[]='.$code->tokens;
    if($key < $num-1){
       $tokens_request .= '&';
    }
}
$activeOrders = Http::acceptJson()->get('https://api.example.com/v2/api?'.$tokens_request);
return $activeOrders;
```

Case 2 (using last token for oauth):

```
$codes = UsersTokens::select('tokens')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
$activeOrders = Http::acceptJson()->withToken($code->tokens)->get('https://api.example.com/v2/api?'.$tokens_request);
return $activeOrders;
```

or:

```
$codes = UsersTokens::select('tokens')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

$activeOrders = Http::acceptJson()->withToken($codes->tokens)->get('https://api.example.com/v2/api?'.$tokens_request);
return $activeOrders;
```

As for second problem updateOrCreate method works with two arrays, in first array are params that should work as unique (system decides if should make new entry or update existing entry based on those params). Exaample:

```
$conditional_entry = SomeModel::updateOrCreate(['param1' => $value1, 'param2' => $value2], ['param3' => $value3, 'param4' => $value4]);
```

Thisl will behave in this way:

```
$conditional_entry = SomeModel::where('param1', $value1)->where('param2', $value2)->first();
if(isset($conditional_entry)){
  $conditional_entry->update(['param3' => $value3, 'param4' => $value4]);
}
else{
  $conditional_entry = SomeModel::create(['param1' => $value1, 'param2' => $value2, 'param3' => $value3, 'param4' => $value4]);
}
```

So your method should look like this:

```
UsersTokens::updateOrCreate(
  [
    'avatar'=>$admin_info['data']['avatar'],
    'name'=>$admin_info['data']['name'],
    'domain'=>$admin_info['data']['domain'],
    'plan'=>$admin_info['data']['plan'],
    'admin'=>$admin_info['data']['name'],
    'mobile'=>$admin_info['data']['mobile'],
    'email'=>$admin_info['data']['email']
],
[
    'token'=>$admin_info['code']
]
);
```

Edit: converted first part to add tokens as URI params
Edit2: added case with using only last token as valid token from oauth2

Comment: I fixed it, but not working for all tokens and i want get url for all tokens from db

Comment: Not sure what you have written in your DB, but call itself should provide only content of tokens field from single row, you might want to check DB if all entries are valid

Comment: I mean Question one, get URL with mutiple tokens, i’m editied post

Comment: Try changing `asJson()` with `accpetJson()`  (first is Eloquent method, not sure why would even work, while later is Http method to add 'Accept: aplication/json' header, and my guess is that that was you intention)

Comment: In fact, this request will have one token, which is the first, while the rest of the tokens are not connected!  I want to make a connection with the same get request for all tokens with the same url

Comment: It's many tokens, and one get url!  I want to connect to each unit's tokens with the same single url, and show me all the results.

Comment: `withToken()` method attaches authorization bearer token to request (only one, as there should be only one valid token), you could pass array as URL params, but then targeted route should be expecting array in request (exmple: `get('https://api.example.com/v2/api?tokens[]=token1&tokens[]=token2')` )

Comment: Good bro, But the count of tokens is not expected, because it is added to the database. It may now be 6 tokens and can be added to the database at any moment

Comment: Is there something like: `withToken()` Receives a larger number of tokens without mentioning the number

Comment: The GET request is an oauth2, not a parameter

Comment: oauth2 accepts only one token as authorization token, and it should be passed in header of request as bearer token (that is what `withToken()` method already does), if you need specific (last generated) token out of multiple written in DB, use orderBy method from Eloquent, will show both cases in edit of answer. In short it is not possible to pass multiple tokens as authorization tokens (such possibility would be considered vulnerability, as breaching system would be easier)

Comment: Thank bro for info, But is there another way to make a get request different tokens?  For example, by for loop or something similar